# SSIS SQL Query Variable Performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, ssis

I was trying to pull data from a OLEDB Source [SQL Server 2008] using SSIS 2012. I tried to pass the date range as parameters to the source query and the performance was very very bad. It was taking more than an hour to pull less than 100k records.

When I changed it to SQL query from variable and did an expression to pass the date range and ran the task and the data pull was quick.

Any idea on how the parameters are passed to the source system and why it caused a huge performance impact.

When I did trace check in source data base the parameters from ssis are passed as  declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P1 datetime',N'SELECT   SQL goes here         where ( START_DATETIME between cast( @P1 as datetime)  and dateadd(hh,-1,getdate()) )',1
select @p1 ..... 
where as if I pass the sql variable when I replace parameter in the string and pass that to the source then output was quick. Same result set difference in Performance.

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Do you see any difference in Profiler?

Comment: Such differences are caused by the query itself, not how it was constructed. In the end, the same source will execute the same query. I'll bet the two queries are *not* the same.